# $FontFamilies returns empty list

Tags: fonts, linux

On version 11.1.1 for Linux x86 I cannot get a list of available fonts.

```
FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]]
```

also returns an empty list.

Menu > Format > Font... brings up a dialogue box listing a large number of fonts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu 17.04, M11.1.1.  I would report this to Wolfram.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for checking/confirming.

Comment: Works fine on a Mac with Mma 11.1.1

Comment: Works also fine on Windows 10 with MM 11.1.1.0

Comment: Wolfram replied: they have also been able to reproduce the problem with Linux version 11.1.1 and are investigating.